# JetBrains IDE font rendering incorrect on Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, windows, fonts, pycharm, webstorm

I recently switched from Windows 11 to Nobara 37 GNOME (Fedora) and found the following problem:
PyCharm and WebStorm display the font differently in Windows and Linux with completely identical IDE settings.

- Font: JetBrains Mono (default)
- Size: 13
- Line height: 1.2
- Antialiasing: Subpixel

| Windows | Linux |
| --- | --- |
| https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTSph.png | https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KA8I.png |

| Overlay |
| --- |
| https://i.stack.imgur.com/V63r0.gif |

As you can see, on Linux, the font is smaller in height and looks "compressed and stretched".
It is extremely inconvenient to work, it hurts the eyes.

IDE Settings
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXwQP.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYEKo.png

What I've already tried:

1. Reinstall the IDE
2. Check the JetBrains Mono font files on Windows and Linux, they turned out to be the same
3. I noticed that on Linux, when font smoothing is turned off, the character height returns to normal, but on Windows, the character height does not change in any way and always remains the same.

Comment: It doesn't look like the problem is with the IDE. Don't you see similar bugs on other applications? Maybe it's some cable misconnected or missing drivers.

Comment: No, everything works fine in other applications. Apparently, this problem is exclusively with the JetBrains Mono font, since if you install a different font in the IDE, the smoothing does not affect the height of the characters in any way.
Also, I tried to install Fedora KDE on a virtual machine and the problem still remained.

Comment: My guess is differences in [OS font enhancement](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=os+font+enhancement). If the IDE settings are exactly the same the problem will be on the OS level. Also, try changing the font itself from JetBrains Mono to something else like Arial and see if the differences persist. I'm also not sure if the font files are the same for Linux/Windows. Are the resolutions the same between the 2 OSs?

Comment: Yes, I tried changing the font to Consolas and Cascadia Code in the IDE and everything works well with them. This problem persists only when using the JetBrains Mono font.  
The screen resolution is 1920x1080 on both systems.
Also, font files are really the same on Windows and Linux. I checked their checksum and got the same result:  
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bEPe.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u9Ak.png

Comment: It seems to be a bug in JetBrains, then. Maybe you can open an issue in their own forum or repository.

Comment: @sidney Yes, I will try to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I was able to achieve about the same result as in Windows. To do this, I had to increase the font by one size (14) and set the line height to 1.1. It seems that this is really an IDE or font problem, since there is no such problem with other fonts.

Comment: So far this works for me. I've been mainly experiencing the issue on **MacOS** and **Linux**.